# Fundamental theorem of calculus part one

Tags: integration

The theorem states:
$$\ F(x) =\int_a^x\ f(t)dt$$
geometrically, this is because we obtain the riemann sum in term of x(if I understand it correctly):

[image: This should be true]

This should be true for any a belongs to [a, b], that is a is taken to be any point in the domain [a, b],   what if we take a to be x and the upper limit to be c belongs to [a, b], shouldn't this be the case, 
$$\ F(x) =\int_x^c\ f(t)dt$$
so,

taking it to the next level:

$$\frac{d\int_a^x\ f(t)dt}{dx}\ =\ f(x)$$ is for x belongs to a to x,
  [image]

now for some x to some a belonging to the same [a, b]  [image]

Shouldn't $$\frac{d\int_x^a\ f(t)dt}{dx}\ =\ f(x)$$ be the same? why would it even be:
$$\frac{-d\int_a^x\ f(t)dt}{dx}\ =\ f(x)$$

I mean, either if we write: 
$$\ F(x) =\int_a^x\ f(t)dt$$
OR, 
$$\ F(x) =\int_x^a\ f(t)dt$$
we would obtain $$F(x)$$ still in terms of x right? Why would we even consider flipping it and then calculating $$ F(x)$$

Is my understand that $$F(x)$$ is obtained in terms of x incorrect, because both ways that I have mentioned above, give us the function in terms of x.

Comment: If $f$ is a positive function, then $g(x) = \int_x^a f(t) dt$ is a decreasing function, and so it's derivative should be negative. So $g'(x) = -f(x)$ makes some sense.

Comment: @Joppy, we're just considering the initial a value to be the unknown, we go from left to right and the y value to be known

Comment: @Joppy, for just replacing the a for x which is unknown and end at a which is known, not flippling the limits which would flip all the why values and the integral is negative makes sense, the very notion of me not understanding is why do we calculate F(x) when it goes from a to x but consider -F(x) when x to a, when we are moving from left to right all along.

Comment: Just because both integrals are functions of $x$ doesn't mean they are the _same_ function of $x$. You're misleading yourself by calling both $$\int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$ and $$\int_{x}^{a} f(t) dt$$ $F(x)$.

Comment: @Mattos, does that mean that it could be G(x), and G(x) may not necessarily be -F(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the function $f(x)$ is positive everywhere, and that
$$F(x) = \int_x^a f(t) \, dt$$
According to your logic, you expect $F'(x)$ to be positive everywhere on its domain, as you claim that $F'(x)=f(x)$. However, imagine that we increase $x$ by a small amount. Then the interval over which $f(t)$ is integrated gets a little bit smaller, causing there to be less area under the curve then before. This is to say, a positive change in $x$ leads to a negative change in $F(x)$, and so it makes sense that $F'(x)$ is negative, and equal to $-f(x)$.

More formally, 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left( \int_{x+h}^a f(t) \, dt- \int_{x}^a f(t) \, dt\right)$$
$$ = -\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left( \int_{x}^a f(t) \, dt- \int_{x+h}^a f(t) \, dt\right)$$
$$ = -\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left( \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t) \, dt\right) = -f(x)$$

Comment: now this _is_ correct!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a Riemann integrable function
$$
\int_{x}^{a} f(t) dt = - \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt
$$

Comment: that's not it, I mentioned it clearly on the question

Answer (score 0):

If $F' = f$ then
$$
\int\limits_a^b f(x) \, dx 
= F(b) - F(a) 
= -(F(a) - F(b)) 
= -\int\limits_b^a f(x) \, dx
$$